# Scala + AspectJ: if() pointcut expressions

Tags: scala, aop, aspectj, sbt-aspectj

I'm using AspectJ library with [sbt-aspectj](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj) in my Scala project.
I'm trying to write `@Pointcut` with `if()` expression:

```
@Aspect
object PerformanceTracer extends Logger {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(PerformanceTracing) && execution(* *(..)) && if()")
  def tracePerfPc(jp: ProceedingJoinPoint): Boolean = {
    // some logic
  }

  @Around("tracePerfPc(jp)")
  def tracePerformance(jp: ProceedingJoinPoint): Object = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis
    log.debug("{}: start proceeding", jp.toShortString)
    val res = jp.proceed
    val duration = System.currentTimeMillis - start
    log.info("[{} ms] {}: end proceeding. Duration: {} ms.", duration, jp.toShortString, duration)
    res
  }
}
```

But I have the following exception:

```
[warn] warning at <Unknown>::0 Found @Pointcut on a method not returning 'void' or not 'public static boolean'
[error] error at <Unknown>::0 Cannot read debug info for @Aspect to handle formal binding in pointcuts (please compile with 'javac -g' or '<javac debug='true'.../>' in Ant)
[error] org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: AspectJ failed
[error]         at com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.runAjcMain(SbtAspectj.scala:212)
[error]         at com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.runAjc(SbtAspectj.scala:124)
[error]         at 
...
```

The [following AspectJ tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html) says:

> It is thus possible with the annotation style to use the if() pointcut
>   only within an @Pointcut expression. The if() must not contain any
>   body. The annotated @Pointcut method must then be of the form public
>   static boolean and can use formal bindings as usual

Is it possible to use `if()` expression in `@Pointcut` on Scala methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that your method signature for `tracePerfPc()` is

```
def tracePerfPc(jp: ProceedingJoinPoint): Boolean
```

or more complete

```
def tracePerfPc(jp: ProceedingJoinPoint): scala.Boolean
```

The type `Boolean` (or `scala.Boolean`) in scala is not the same as the Java `boolean` which is a primitive type and no object.

So you cannot use `if()` in AspectJ together with a return value as the primitive type `boolean` does not exists in native scala.